# MySQL driver for node.js to work with Sphinx

Tags: mysql, node.js, sphinx, npm

Which drivers out there...

- have support for all or most features of MySQL;
- are actively maintained;
- are asynchronous and support pipes;
- **can interface with [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com)**?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818312/mysql-with-node-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used a couple but this is my choice:

node-mysql
https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

Well maintained and documented. The author is a node.js contributor and one of the founders of transloadit, I believe. As well as the author of node-formidable.

Comment: Thanks! Node.js contributor is a very good objective indication!