# Replacing JavaScript/PHP ajax request with node.js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm having a web application which is using PHP/MySQL pair. Now i like to replace only the AJAX requests to node.js to reduce the latency to less than 1 second. So when i googled about this, i came to know about node.js as the efficient way to implement this. But it is not possible for me to replace the entire PHP system to node.js, so i'm in the idea of only changing the AJAX requests to node (The current system is in JQuery/PHP). So i like to know about the possibility and some guidance of changing only the AJAX requests to node.js. Any idea or directions on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there is not much difference on how it works in the clientside, just point the url at the node driven web entry point.

Comment: The client doesn't know about the way the backend works. Just start to implement the Ajax stuff in node and let the node server serve the calls. From the outside it should just be a url.

Comment: @KevinBoss Is it possible to use the MySQL DB queries that i have written already in PHP for this purpose or do i have to change them also to node?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818312/mysql-with-node-js <- I just give you this (doesn't make sense to copy this stuff over here) :)