# node js socket.io mysql connection, add, update, delete

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, socket.io

i want to save my feeds to database in nodejs and socket.io but i haven't any article about mysql connection in nodejs. I want to feeds to save to mysql database, load to page without refresh. How must i do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818312/mysql-with-node-js

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql). A pure node.js JavaScript Client implementing the MySql protocol.
Maybe it's a good idea to create some Client side models with Backbone and Marionette to send a request to the server to persist the data.

Take a look at: [Marionette and Backbone](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette)