# Order by reference property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have `User` schema:

```
{
    name: String
    ...
}
```

I also have `Contract` schema:

```
{
    user: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
    ...
}
```

Then i want to sort contracts like this:

```
ContractModel.find().sort({ "user.name": -1 }).exec(...);
```

Is it possible somehow without getting all data? Or what are alternative solutions? Thanks

Comment: I could nealy post this as a *"kind of"* answer. But surely this **must** be a duplicate. MongoDB is **not** relational. It **does not** do joins. If you **need** that then use a relational database and **do not** use MongoDB. Or possibly change your thinking, maybe?

Comment: @NeilLunn I asked if there were alternative solutions. How to do this without relations?

Comment: You do not present enough information here for an informative answer. If you want one then **please** provide more information. But the principles are simple. If you **want** to use "related" information on a **regular** basis then **embed**. But if you can embellish on your question and otherwise expect a different "answer" then go ahead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node - Mongoose 3.6 - Sort query with populated field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428471/node-mongoose-3-6-sort-query-with-populated-field)