# mongoose-paginate sorting by referenced document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination, mongoose-plugins

I would like to sort my `Group`-Model by the `name` of the `departure_country` with mongoose-paginate and NodeJS.

My **Group-Schema**:

```
  var GroupSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        flight_date: Date,
        ....
        departure_country: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Country'},
        ....
  });
```

The **Country-Schema**:

```
 var CountrySchema = new Schema({
     name: String,
     code: String,
 });
```

Using the `sortBy`-option of mongoose-paginate sorts by the country's `_ids` and I don't know how to tell it to sort by the `name`.

Comment: How do you apply `sortBy`?

Comment: `sortBy({departure_country: -1})` right now

Comment: Have you tried `{"departure_country.name": -1}`?

Comment: But in fact I don't think that would be possible as it's a populated field and 'joining' is done in the app level, not mongoose level. You could include country name in your `GroupSchema` and sort by it

Comment: Of course :) did not work. Neither did `{"departure_country": {"name": -1}}`

Comment: Why can't you include country name in the `GroupSchema`? See my previous comment.

Comment: Sometimes you don´t want to sort by the county name but maybe by the country code. Including that field as a non-referenced field does not seem very nice to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92183/discussion-between-molerat-and-vsevolod-goloviznin).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node - Mongoose 3.6 - Sort query with populated field](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19428471/1202461).

Comment: I see, you are right and Vsevolod also told me the same thing

Comment: {"departure_country.name": -1} - this will work with only nested documents, not references

Answer (score 0):

how about making the country code the _id of Country-Schema?

then `departure_country: {type: String, ref: 'Country'}`

That might actually be a better design. `Country-Schema`s _id would be small, and country codes shouldn't have collisions. Also in `GroupSchema` you'd use less space to store the "foreign key" `departure_country`.

then you'd be able to sort by `departure_country` and there's a chance the sort would also be valid for country name.

Comment: sometimes I need to display or even sort by the name of the country as well

Comment: @molerat don't think there's a way to do that since you're populating. you'd have to do that on the nodejs side. http://underscorejs.org has good functions for that. sortBy or even groupBy could be useful.

Comment: If you get 50 of 10000 entries and sort those only, you will not have the same result as if sorting 10000 and then picking 50.

Comment: it's a consequence of data normalization in mongo. back to what I suggested, I think it can even work if you use the country name as an id. provided you have a pre-defined set of countries - so they're not user input (if they are user input, you need a way to normalize the name string to avoid duplicates). You could also make departure country an object and have both the id and the country name in there.