# How to setup MySQL in combination with Node.js

Tags: mysql, database, web-services, node.js, lamp

I am making a Restful API using Node.js.

My project requires using MySQL Database (since there is an existing MySQL DB which needs to be re-designed). Therefore, **what is the best way to setting up the new MySQL? Using bundle like LAMP or standalone MySQL?**

- LAMP will provide me the traditional administration tool phpMyAdmin (export, import, visualization...).
- Installing MySQL alone seems more tidy but there is no "mature" administration tool yet. I can only find this one https://github.com/simov/express-admin.

Can you please tell me the pros and cons of each way? Thank you in advance.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is a seperate php based admin tool for MySql and can be set up independently of MySQL ... so not sure about your question

Comment: I would like to have an administration tool for MySQL. As I am understand, phpMyAdmin is the most popular one and it requires Apache, PHP to run http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/require.html.

Comment: Yes that is true ... you can always use the command line tools

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818312/mysql-with-node-js

Comment: @NamHoang https://github.com/simov/express-admin is a web UI for end users, which means you can only add/modify/remove records. It's not designed for managing databases - like create/drop tables and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also recommend [mySQL with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818312/mysql-with-node-js) for getting started. Your best bet for administration tools would be to use a standalone client to tunnel into your database, like [MySQL Workbench](http://mysqlworkbench.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I am using Workbench, but mostly for designing DB schema. Regarding administration, I find that the command line tool is not bad.