# Best practice solution to create a Web Service for an Android app

Tags: java, android, xml, json, web-services

I am planning to write a `Web Service` in Java which connects to a MySQL Database and computes and exposes different information from it.

Then an `Android` app will connect to this `Web Service` and process the information.

Initially I thought of using `XML` files, but I was advised that it is not the best-practice correct way, and the Service part will not be light weight. That I should use `JSON`.

What is the correct architecture and solution for my problem ?

Also is it possible to run a Java Web Service without Tomcat, directly by the JVM from a jar?

Any documentation or links would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, for android its better to use JSON, its native API (built in)
and its much lighter.
also , its recommended to use RESTful service, for the same reasons (performance, lighter )

regarding the webservice without tomcat, i am not sure its possible, because you always need a container to manage and run your code.

here is a good tutorial to create RESTful service using Jersy.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

the sample shows data as XML, you can change to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `node.js`. This will not require Tomcat or any other application server since it itself hots a HTTP server in itself.

https://blog.nodejitsu.com/a-simple-webservice-in-nodejs/

[MySQL with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818312/mysql-with-node-js)