# Invoke PHP to MySQL script from command line on arduino

Tags: php, mysql, linux, arduino

I'm trying to insert data to a MySQL database from an arduino yun (which runs a linux distribution). I was told on the arduino forums that the first thing I need to do is write a PHP script that I can invoke from the command line and that can connect and insert data into my mysql database.

I've already figured out how to create a web form and php script to insert into a MySQL database.

As a complete novice could you please guide me?

Much appreciated,

Charlie

Comment: Have you already created (and installed) the database system? what distribution are you using on your arduino yun? what web server are you using? Moreover, I would suggest you, instead of using PHP, to use nodejs and the nodejs mysql extention, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818312/mysql-with-node-js . To me, nodejs is way faster rather than PHP and it's also a good way to keep everything inside nodejs, allowing you to totally be able to work using javascript only. (Also, nodejs provides a very suitable Serial library)

Comment: if i am not mistaken, all you need now is "how to run that php script from arduino"? Sorry if this sounds mean but isn't this something you should go back to Arduino forums for?