# MySQL for node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am trying to create a database for my node.js server using MySQL. I am aware of the node-mysql module. I found an example [here](http://blog.josedacruz.com/2013/07/19/learning-node-js-using-mysql/#.U9_EZ-OSyXh) but am not able to make it work. I have MySQL Workbench installed on my computer, will that do? Or do I have to install something else from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/)? Please point me to some nice tutorials for setting up a connection between my server and MySQL.

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818312/mysql-with-node-js) to this question may help.

Comment: @SLaks: Well, in the mysql.createConnection() method from http://blog.josedacruz.com/2013/07/19/learning-node-js-using-mysql/#.U9_TZuOSyXi what are the host and port parameters?

Comment: The hostname and port that your MySQL server is running on.

Comment: do you already have mysql running on a server?

Comment: @Markasoftware: I hadn't installed the MySQL server. All set now