# Portable Mysql with Electron

Tags: mysql, electron

I just checked Electron to create desktop applications. It is looking impressive. I want to know that where to store data in electron. Is there any portable mysql available for electron? So that it will be easy to create apps and distribute it which requires a database like mysql.

Comment: maybe check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391675/access-a-mysql-database-in-electron
or this - https://github.com/garrylachman/ElectroCRUD

Comment: This question is different, I am looking for portable mysql which is compatible with electron package.

Comment: OK my fault - there were some attempts to make mysql portable version - like here - https://sourceforge.net/projects/miniserver/files/MiniServer/MiniServer_%20MySQL%205.0.67%20Portable/

But maybe you could try this - http://www.sqlabs.com/cubesql.php - standalone database based on SQLite3. SQLite3 is widely supported and has very clear syntax.

On the other hand - what about Docker version of MySQL? Or you can create your own Docker image containing MySQL + Electron. It will be portable enough I guess.