# Configuring MySQL with Node.js from AMP project

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin, node-mysql

I am trying to migrate an existing MySQL + PHP project (with phpMyAdmin) to server-side javascript (Node.js and Express). I am wondering how best to establish a MySQL connection with Node, given that the current setup is on phpMyAdmin? That is, is it possible to configure the node-mysql connection such that it finds the host on phpMyAdmin?

In case the above is not possible, I would like to allow collaborators access to this database. Setting up remote MySQL connections to my localhost MySQL database seems to be one solution, but I have run into difficulty in following this post for two reasons: [How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql).

1. An /etc/mysql folder does not exist on my system (cannot find my.cnf)
2. Upon granting remote access, I'm unsure how to specify the host and/or ip address for other users that will be connecting remotely to my localhost MySQL db.

Comment: 23 seconds of Googling brought me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818312/mysql-with-node-js and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql. Do they help any?

Comment: I've skimmed through both of those. Sorry my original post was unclear, I rephrased my question.